# Laravel , Eloquent delete not working

Tags: laravel, frameworks, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and Oracle XE 11 with yajra/laravel-oci8 plugin.
When I try to delete or edit a record with Eloquent it's not working.

My table:

[image: My table]

Model object to delete:

[image]

id_contact in last query is null instead binding with id in find()

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you do `dd($cd->getKey())` and post the output?

Comment: it's return null value

Comment: And what does `$cd->getKeyName()` return?

Comment: It's return the name of table primary key "ID_CONTACT"

Comment: Hmm... What if you try to access that manually? `$cd->ID_CONTACT` (if that's null try `$cd->id_contact`)

Comment: Actually if I using default primary key (id), delete method is working

Comment: Hmm, if i call $cd->ID_CONTACT it's return null value, but if i call $cd->id_contact it's return the value, thank you,  you're save my day, the problem is because in primaryKey i define with uppercase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason the db adapter converts the uppercase column names into lowercase causing the attributes in your model to be all lowercase. Therefore you should access them in lowercase and also specify the primary key in lowercase:

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'id_contact';
```